# Problem with ADC of Atmega16A in differential mode

Tags: adc, atmega, buffer

I am having some problem while using ADC interface of Atmega16A. I want to calculate RMS voltage of the power supply coming to my house(usually 250V, 50Hz) and display it on LCD. I am using the following circuit. But I am facing some problem that I don't understand at all.[image]

I haven't shown all the connections here. A 16x2 LCD is connected to PORTB(D0:D7 pins of LCD) and PORTD(RS,RW and En pins to PORTD4,PORTD5,PORTD6). The problem is as soon as I connect the output pin of LM741, the voltage on this pin drops to zero as if the input resistance of the ADC is zero.

The ADMUX reads as ADMUX = 0b01010000.(REFS1:0 is 01, ADLAR is 0, MUX4:0 is 10000)  I am using 24MHz external crystal.

Comment: What is the analogue input voltage range expected from your MCU and what are you possibly feeding it with? Is there no signal present when you connect the MCU?

Comment: @Andyaka No, there is no signal present when I connect the MCU. By the way I think you got the mistake right, "What is the analogue input voltage range expected from your MCU and what are you possibly feeding it with". The circuit above would possibly be feeding a signal ranging from -3Vrms to +3Vrms and I think only 0V to Vcc is allowed for ADC conversion. That is why it's not working and probably the atmega has damaged already.

Comment: OK you possibly have your disappointing answer - I'll formalize it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 741 will produce bipolar voltages that could easily damage the ADC input. Note that the ADC is intended for ADC voltages from 0V to a positive voltage determined by a voltage reference but the 741 will produce an AC waveform centred around 0V. I'm not saying it is definitely this but it doesn't look like it could be anything else. Maybe trying moving to a spare ADC input but be prepared to throw away the device (or try a new one).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an isolation resistor between the opamp and the adc input? Also, verify that the opamp Vp pin has the expected waveform.

Comment: I haven't tried using an isolation resistor yet, let me do it and I will let you know. But what is Vp pin for? I don't see any such pin in 741.

Comment: I tried with an isolation resistor but that didn't helped. The signal at the input of the adc is still attenuated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with a solution for the above problem. I am posting the solution here as I think it may help someone else later. The circuit is as follows. I added a offset of 2.5V to the output of the buffer so that the input voltage to the ADC stays within range. Now it works just fine. Also now I am measuring the input voltage in single ended mode.

[image]

Where VCC = 5V, V+ = 12V, V- = -12V